# Cookies not found the first time after they're set

Tags: javascript, cookies

On my local host I've several pages. The first page sets a cookie to preserve some data. All pages read the cookie and display the data. Everything works perfect in Chrome as well as in IE7. The files on my remote host are copies of the ones on localhost so they are exactly the same. If I visit the pages on my remote host however, in Chrome the cookie can't be found but after reloading the page or visiting another one, the cookie is normaly found and the data are displayed correctly. So each time JavaScript tries to find the cookie directly after it's set on the previous page, it can't be found but on all next times there's no problem. If I visit the pages on my remote host with IE7, the cookie can't be found at all although it appears to be set correctly.

Can anyone explain this difference in behaviour between localhost and remote host and between IE7 and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was a fault in the getCookie function so it could only find the first cookie. Since there was always only one cookie set this problem never showed up. After adding the script used for Google Analytics, more cookies were set but such is not the case on localhost. That explains the difference in behaviour between localhost and remote host. The next thing to explain is how the cookie could stil be found in Chrome after reloading the page on which they were not set. Problably Chrome places already existing cookies above in the list and and IE does not.